# Firefox freezes when working with big array of objects

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a single-page JS app where I have a big array of objects to store application state. When I update this state Firefox freezes for a few seconds and shows the following message: "A web page is slowing down your browser"

[image: firefox web page is slowing down your browser]

Surprisingly, it works just fine in Chrome. Obviously, the app could be optimized to avoid having such big state but I'm looking for simpler ways.

This is how I update the state:

```js
    return {
        ...state,
        data: state.data.map(item => {
            if (item.id !== updated.id) {
                return item;
            }
            return {...item, ...updated}
        })
    };
```

From what I can tell the freeze caused by any operations with the array (`state.data`) not just map. I tried all kind of solutions: not using spread operator, with for loops, forEach, splice, slice, not using merge, finding index but it's always either freeze or the app doesn't detect state update. Any suggestions?

Comment: Likely the best way is to use a WebWorker for such CPU-intensive tasks.

Comment: Maybe use some kind of async iterator/generator to iterate the items outside a tight loop?

Comment: unfortunately, I have my state updated in rxjs reducer which must be a pure function. And all this running inside zone.js which afaik doesn't support async-await